# what's the meaning of "made his remarks ... concrete"

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of "made his remarks ... concrete"

> He never made his remarks on the relation between biopolitics and 
>   liberalism concrete. [(source)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cRVNFqFPGtoC&pg=PA50&dq=%22relation%20between%20biopolitics%20and%20liberalism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4QInU5z2MOeO4wThj4DQBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22relation%20between%20biopolitics%20and%20liberalism%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

To make a thought or concept concrete means to be specific and exact, and usually to include "concrete examples"  -- examples that leave no question as to the specificity of the idea.

This is related to "solidifying" an idea (concrete is an example of a solid object, thus the metaphor): taking it from an ethereal concept and bringing it closer to reality by avoiding generic, lofty language and instead providing exact details and contingencies.